# Jasmine - Testing for undefined method in object

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a very basic question. How do I check if a method is defined in an object using jasmine? So far I have:

```
expect(obj.method).not.toBeUndefined();
```

But the report unhelpfully states:

```
'Expected undefined not to be undefined.'
```

It would be great if, somehow, it could tell me the name of the property I tried looking for in the report.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JS engine evaluates `obj.method` before it is even passed to the `expect` function. Hence, there is no way to recover the string `"method"` from within the matcher.

You should [write your own matcher](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Matchers) that takes the method name as an argument of type string.

Something like

```
expect(obj).toHaveMethod("method");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use something like...

```
var validMethod = obj.hasOwnProperty('method') 
                  && typeof obj.method == 'function';
```

Comment: Not sure how that really ties in with Jasmine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should simply do

```
 it("The 'toBeDefined' matcher compares against `undefined`", function() {
    var a = {
      foo: 'foo'
    };

    expect(a.foo).toBeDefined();
    expect(a.bar).not.toBeDefined();
  });
```